# How to change the settings type and position of a kivy app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I not able to find out how to change the type of the displayed settings panel used in my kivy app. I currently use following code to create the panel:

```
def build_config(self, config):
    config.read("settings.ini")
    App.build_config(self, config)

def build_settings(self, settings):
    settings.size_hint = (0.8, 0.8)
    settings.pos = (200,200)
    settings.interface_cls = SettingsWithSidebar()
    settings.add_json_panel("General Settings", self.config,
                            filename="settings_general.json")
    settings.add_json_panel("Analysis", self.config,
                            filename="settings_analysis.json")
    App.build_settings(self, settings)
```

That gives me the standard `SettingsWithSidebar` panel, which looks relatively ugly. I want to change that to standard `Settings` panel, which looks imo much nicer, but cannot find out how to do it. 
I looked at the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html) and found the `interface_cls` property, but changing its value to `Settings()` or `SettingsWithSidebar()` seems to do nothing.

My second problem is that i do not know how to set the position of the settings panel according to the position of the app (the 200,200 are a placeholder). I know how that can be accomplished in kv-language, but i do not know how i can reference the pos of the app before it is created. I do want to bind the center of the settings panel to the center of the application window, but i cannot find sources on how to accomplish that task.

Comment: I suspect you should leave off the `()` when setting your `interface_cls`.

Comment: You mean i should simply set it  to "Settings" instead of "Settings()"? I also tried that but it also did not work.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Actually, I think `Settings` is the same as `SettingsWithSidebar`. Look at the [documenttion](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html#different-panel-layouts) and choose a class from there that is identified as a `settings widget `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution to my problem:
To use any other Settings panel than the standard one, one has to change the `settings_cls` property of the **App** class, not of the Settings itself. This can be done by adding

```
self.settings_cls = Settings # Desired settings class
```

to the build method of the app.

To change the position of the Settings popup, one has to change the pos_hint of Settings object given to the build_settings method of the app class. Example: To change the size of the settings window to 90% of the app size and then position it in the center of the app, one has to add:

```
settings.pos_hint = ({"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5})
settings.size_hint = (0.9, 0.9)
```

to the build_settings method (where settings is the settings object passed to the method) before calling `App.build_settings(self, settings)`.